# Why grant select on view does not grant permission in all necessary objects to select it?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7 I've tried

```
grant select on sys.innodb_lock_waits to 'zbx_monitor'@'%';
```

But I got the error the selecting it with zbx_monitor user.

```
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'sys.innodb_lock_waits' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

So I solve it granting permission in a function used in this view and now it worked.

```
grant execute on function sys.format_statement to 'zbx_monitor'@'%';
```

But in MySQL 8.0 I need to grant execute in `quote_identifier` function as well, but still does not work, I got the following error:

```
ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'zbx_monitor'@'%' for column 'ENGINE_LOCK_ID' in table 'data_locks'
```

Why does a simple grant select in the view does not work? Is this right? I need to grant in individual objects as well inside the view? I mean, a view should abstract everything, including permissions?

Edit: I solve the error in MySQL 8.0 with:

```
GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.data_lock_waits TO 'zbx_monitor'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.data_locks TO 'zbx_monitor'@'%';
```

But I still doesn't undestand why a single grant select on the view `sys.innodb_lock_waits` does not work.

Comment: The server protects you from unwanted assignment of excessive permissions. You may not know, ignore or forget some dependencies, and as a result, the user may have permissions that he should not have.